# How to convert Stream<T> to Stream<E> in dart

Tags: dart

I have one Stream of type T. I want to convert into some other type like Stream of E. Can someone tell me how can i achieve it?

Comment: If your `Stream<T>` is actually already a `Stream<E>` (that is, you just need to cast the element types rather than doing a conversion), you could use [`stream.cast<E>()`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-async/Stream/cast.html).

Comment: what if T and E is different data class? will cast work?

Comment: If `T` and `E` are unrelated classes, then no, it won't work. `Stream<T>.cast<E>` would work only if a `T` is castable (e.g. with `as`) to an `E`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You will want to use the map function. Its purpose is just this

https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.9.1/dart-async/Stream/map.html

A simple example:

```
var intstream = Stream.fromIterable([1,2,3]);
var stringstream = intstream.map<String>((e){return "$e";});
```

Answer (score 0):

if anyone wants to convert `Stream<List<T>` to `Stream<List<K>>`

```dart
extension StreamListExtension<T, K> on Stream<List<T>> {
  Stream<List<K>> mapList<K>(K Function(T) mapper) {
    return map((list) => list.map(mapper).toList());
  }
}
```